# Creating Circular VideoView in Android

Tags: android, android-videoview

How to create a circular VideoView in android? I tried creating it but get something like this. I want the extra part outside the circle to be either cropped out or masked.  Is there anything similar to ios api maskToBounds or clipToBounds in android? How to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Make your own custom video view but extending VideoView

Comment: Ya tried with that. But not able to accomplish.